# variables in static function and normal function

Tags: c, variables, static

I know the difference between static function and normal function in C, my question is: Is there any difference between the variables declared in a static function and the variables declared in a normal function in C?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about normal variables in static and normal function or static and normal variables in static and normal function? I am bit confused here.

Comment: I mean the normal variables in static and normal function.

Answer (score 3):

> **Is there any difference between the variables declared in a static function and the variables declared in a normal function in C?**

Answer: NO there is no difference

Answer (score 1):

No, the `static` keyword only applies to visibility when applied to a function.

The `static` keyword for functions tells the compiler/linker that the function should not be visible outside the file. When applied to a function, `static` in C is equivalent to `private` in languages like Java or C++.

Comment: *The `static` keyword for functions tells the compiler/linker that the function should not be visible outside the class* No, this is not correct. `static` functions in C++ are not related to access specification. Access specifiers do that. `static` in C governs the linkage. It gives the function an *internal* linkage(*default linkage is external*). Internal linkage limits the scope  and hence visibility of the function/variable in the same Translation unit.

Comment: Since when did C have classes? Your second statement claims so. And what you state is incorrect. Just comparing one trait and claiming the two separate language constructs to be same is simply incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Variables declared in functions have nothing to do with their storage class type. All variables defined in a function (static or not), will have their scope defined until the function exits.
Whereas, a function being static or not will only define it's visibility to other files.

Answer (score 1):

The term `static` used in a static function makes that function scope only to that particular `.c` file. This will not do anything to the variables (`auto`, `static` or `register`) declared inside that static function.

Answer (score 1):

Both variables are `automatic`, hence they are allocated on the stack.

Comment: The best answer to this question.